# Dynamic Fields js/php to MySql need to submit dynamically to the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, dynamic

I can not get the values from the javascript add row to go dynamically as a row into MySql only the form values show up as the form below as one row. I made it as an array, but no such luck, I have tried this code around a multitude of ways. I don't know what I am doing wrong, kindly write out the correct way.

My code for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Dynamic Fields js/php to MySql need to submit dynamically to the database</title>
<?php
require ('database.php'); 
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var counter     =     1;
 var collector     =     "";

 function addfields(indx)
 {
     var tbl = document.getElementById('table_id');
     var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
     counter = counter + indx;

     newtr.setAttribute('id','tr'+counter);

     newtr.innerHTML = '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkb'+counter+'" id="checkb'+counter+'" value="'+counter+'" onclick="checkme('+counter+')"></td><td><input type="text" name="text1[]"></td><td><textarea name="textarea1[]"></textarea></td>';

     tbl.appendChild(newtr);
 }

 function checkme(dx)
{
      collector += dx+",";
}

 function deletetherow(indx)
 {
     var col = collector.split(",");

     for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) 
     {
         var remvelem = document.getElementById('tr'+col[i]);
         var chckbx = document.getElementById("checkb"+col[i]);
         if(remvelem && chckbx.checked)
         {
             var tbl = document.getElementById('table_id');
            tbl.removeChild(remvelem);
        }
     }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="1" style="background-color:#ffffff;" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"></form> 
<table id="table_id" >
  <tr id="tr1" class="trmain">
  <td>
  </td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="text1[]">
    </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="textarea1[]"></textarea>
       </td>  
     </tr>
 </table>
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addfields(1);" />&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="deletetherow()" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"  name="submit"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['text1']); $i++ )
{
$ced = stripslashes($_POST['text1'][$i]);
$erg = stripslashes($_POST['textarea1'][$i]);
      $bnt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (first, second) VALUES ('$ced', '$erg')")or     
      die ('Error: '. mysql_error() );
}
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are overwritting `$ced` and `$erg` on each loop, and so only the final values will be inserted.  Place your `$bnt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename ...` inside your `for()` loop. Also, why are you  why are you double querying -> `$result = mysql_query($bnt);`? Since `$bnt = mysql_query(` this second `$result = mysql_query(` is not needed.

Comment: Sean, thanks for the reply, I have edited the code. The $result=MySQL_query(... was originally assigned a success message and I didn't add the whole code, sorry. Anyway, it still posts into the DB only the first set of values, I do understand logically where as my array to include the MySQL. I tried to explode the data but I just couldn't figure that out if that is what I should be doing? Any further advice or can you get this working. Again, thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perma link for anyone: [Dynamic Fields js/php to MySql need to submit dynamically to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25466071/3935687)

If you are seeking answer to this subject, then Sean was right, it actually never overwrote the other as just first inputs submitted to MySQL as others ignored as wasn't part of loop. His innerhtml dynamic with loop is working.

If you want the code, its' above-edited or take from perma. There are not a whole lot of these working examples on the web, now you can go further with jQuery with this and getting more popular.